# SQL Query to retrieve data on 2016 Presidential Election demographics, google trends, and votes

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Query 1]

I tried - but it does not present the correct order

`SELECT * FROM demographics d INNER JOIN votes v ON d.CountyID = v.CountyID GROUP BY d.state ORDER BY republican DESC`

[image: Query 2]

I tried - but there is a syntax error near line 4 and I cannot determine how to join both the google trends, demographics, and votes tables while successfully referencing the google search_trump to a national average since national average doesn't exist and must be calculated

```
SELECT 
    d.State
    , SUM(v.Democrats) AS total_votes_democrat
    , SUM(v.Republican) AS total_votes_republican
    , SUM(v.Others) AS total_votes_other
    , SUM(d.Total_Population) AS total_population
    , AVG(d.Percent_White) AS avg_per_white
    , AVG(d.Percent_Black) AS avg_per_black
    , AVG(d.Percent_Asian) AS avg_per_asian
    , AVG(d.PerCapita_Income) AS avg_inc_per_capita
    , AVG(d.Median_Rent) AS avg_median_rent 
FROM 
    demographics d INNER JOIN votes v ON v.CountyID = d.CountyID 
    INNER JOIN googletrends g ON g.State = d.State 
WHERE g.GoogleSearch_Trump > SUM(GoogleSearch_Trump, GoogleSearch_Clinton)/2
```

TABLES INCLUDE: demographics, google trends, votes

COLUMNS INCLUDE:

Demographics - (CountyID, Name, State, total_population, percent_white, percent_black, percent_asian, percent_hispanic, per capita_income, median_rent, median_age)

Googletrends - (state, google search_trump, google search_clinton)

Votes - (CountyID, democrats, republican, others)

Answer (score 0):

sun has no such function of sum with comma

So instead of

```
WHERE g.GoogleSearch_Trump > SUM(GoogleSearch_Trump, GoogleSearch_Clinton)/2
```

You need something like the `SUM` of the new sum could be better

```
WHERE g.GoogleSearch_Trump > (GoogleSearch_Trump + GoogleSearch_Clinton)/2
```

but you must check your results, using aggregation  functions without `GROUP BY` can give unwanted results

Comment: tried using the function recommended still receiving syntax error unsure why

Comment: which error exactly? also can you add some data to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ac988869001c9e8c21820cd607f55b4 and post the new link

Comment: Code 1064 - I'm new to SQL and stack overflow. I will try to learn to use the link you requested that I add data to. The response gives that the error is near ')'

Comment: Just fixed the syntax error - small mistake on my part. Reviewing now to see if this is the correct result.